# React JS + Material UI throwing leftNav is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I was trying to implement React JS with Material UI and got stuck on a problem with Left Nav Bar Toggling behavior.

I have created the components using Yeoman commands.

There are 2 component

BodyComponent - Parent

HeaderCompoent- Child

In Body Component i have created the menuItem and LeftNavBar and in the HeaderComponent i have created AppBar with **onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this._handleTouch}** event but when i click on the hamburger icon it throws navLeft is undefined.

As per my understanding the problem here is the event is called on the child and reference of LeftNavBar is in parent, which is somehow i am not able to access it.

i have read that these can be solved iether but putting all the component together rather than separating but i don't want to separate it, also i don't want to use flux to fix this one issue.

Is there any good solution for this ? or do i have to change the way i written my code ? if yes, how ?

**Body Component**

```
/*jshint esnext: true */
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import mui from 'material-ui';
import Header from './HeaderComponent';

require('styles//Body.sass');

const LeftNav = require('material-ui/lib/left-nav');
const Tabs = require('material-ui/lib/tabs/tabs');
const Tab = require('material-ui/lib/tabs/tab');
const MenuItem = mui.MenuItem;

// injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
// injectTapEventPlugin();


var menuItems = [{
  route: 'device',
  text: 'Device'
}, {
  type: MenuItem.Types.SUBHEADER,
  text: 'xyz'
}, {
  route: 'xyz1',
  text: 'xyz1'
}, {
  route: 'xyz2',
  text: 'xyz2'
}, {
  route: 'xyz3',
  text: 'xyz3'
}, {
  type: MenuItem.Types.LINK,
  payload: 'https://github.com/callemall/material-ui',
  text: 'GitHub'
}, {
  text: 'Disabled',
  disabled: true
}, {
  type: MenuItem.Types.LINK,
  payload: 'https://www.google.com',
  text: 'Disabled Link',
  disabled: true
}];


class BodyComponent extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      < div className = "body-component" >
      < LeftNav ref = "leftNav"
        header = { < Header / > }
        docked = { true }
        menuItems = { menuItems }/>
      < Tabs >
        < Tab label = "Item One" >
        (Tab content...)
        < /Tab>
        < Tab label = "Item Two" >
        (Tab content...)
        < /Tab>
        < Tab label = "Item Three"
        route = "home"
        onActive = {
          this._handleTabActive
        }>
        </ Tab>
      < /Tabs>
      < /div>
    );
  }
}

BodyComponent.displayName = 'BodyComponent';

// Uncomment properties you need
// BodyComponent.propTypes = {};
// BodyComponent.defaultProps = {};

export default BodyComponent;
```

**Header Component**

```
/*jshint esnext: true */
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import Body from './BodyComponent';
import mui from 'material-ui';
const AppBar = require('material-ui/lib/app-bar');

//import ActionCreator from '../actions/AppBarActionCreators';
const injectTapEventPlugin = require("react-tap-event-plugin");
injectTapEventPlugin();


require('styles//Header.sass');


class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {

  _handleTouch() {
    console.log(this);
    this.refs.leftNav.toggle();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header-component">
      < AppBar title = "vEDM"
      onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this._handleTouch}
      iconClassNameRight = "muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more" / >
      </div>
    );
  }
}
HeaderComponent.displayName = 'HeaderComponent';

export default HeaderComponent;
```

Answer (score 1):

in the `BodyComponent`, you can create a function to toggle the leftNav and pass it as props in the `Header`

**Body**

```
class BodyComponent extends React.Component {

  toggleLeftNav() {
    this.refs.leftNav.toggle();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      < div className = "body-component" >
      < LeftNav ref = "leftNav"
        header = { < Header toggleLeftNav={ this.toggleLeftNav.bind(this) } /> }
        docked = { true }
        menuItems = { menuItems }/>
      < Tabs >
        < Tab label = "Item One" >
        (Tab content...)
        < /Tab>
        < Tab label = "Item Two" >
        (Tab content...)
        < /Tab>
        < Tab label = "Item Three"
        route = "home"
        onActive = {
          this._handleTabActive
        }>
        </ Tab>
      < /Tabs>
      < /div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Header**

```
class HeaderComponent extends React.Component {

  _handleTouch() {
       this.props.toggleLeftNav();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="header-component">
      < AppBar title = "vEDM"
      onLeftIconButtonTouchTap={this._handleTouch.bind(this)}
      iconClassNameRight = "muidocs-icon-navigation-expand-more" / >
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: no luck. i tried console.log(this.props) inside _handleTouch, it gives undefined.

Comment: @SharathBangera i updated the answer, added the `bind(this)` to bind to the class instance